# Can a Russian national fly to Latin America with a stop in Europe, such as TAP Airlines stop in Portugal?

Tags: stopovers, russian-language

Are there sanctions against travelers? Transit visa hell? Basically, can a Russian national fly to Latin America with a layover / stop in Europe, such as TAP Airlines stop in Portugal?

Comment: Is TAP flying to Russia now?

Comment: Does Istanbul count as "Europe"?

Comment: There are no "sanctions" against ordinary Russians in EU. None are planned either.